# Including a jQuery file seems to overwrite my background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an htm file named "registrationpage2" and it includes various links and scripts, however one line in particular:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

is causing issues.  When I include the line, my background is no longer visible. When I comment out the line, the background becomes visible again however I lose the formatting that the js file was responsible for. I tried moving around the order of the links but I've had no luck, please help.  The file that specifies the background is "style.css", I can include post the code for that as well if necessary.

This is my registrationpag2 file, the line that causes the issue is the 10th element in the header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>Registration | Theme 1</title>

 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script src="registration_v.0.1/theme_1/js/addons.js"></script>
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- this is the line that causes the issue  -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://campaign.gear.host/registration_v.0.1/theme_1/css/style.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://campaign.gear.host/registration_v.0.1/theme_1/ui/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
 <div id="left_side">
  <div id="container">
   <hgroup>
    <h1>Search</h1>
   </hgroup>
   <article id="article">
    <form class="<form">
     <fieldset>          
      <a href="AdminPage.html" title="Admin Link">Admin</a>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
       <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Basic Criteria</h1>
        <input><p>First Name</p></input>
        <input><p>Middle Name</p></input>
        <input><p>Last Name</p></input>
        <input><p>Voter Title</p></input>
        <input><p>State Voter ID</p></input>
        <input><p>Registration Date</p></input>
        <input><p>Original Register Date</p></input>
        <input><p>Gender</p></input>
        <input><p>City/Town</p></input>
        <input><p>Country</p></input>
        <input><p>Starting Age Range</p></input>
        <input><p>Ending Age Range</p></input>
        <input><p>Company</p></input>
        <input><p>Preferred Language</p></input>
        <input><p>E-mail Address</p></input>
        <input><p>Phone</p></input>
        <input><p>Phone Location</p>
         <select name="PhoneLocation" id="Phone Location">
          <option value="1">Home</option>
          <option value="3">Main</option>
          <option value="4">Other</option>
          <option value="2">Work</option>
          <option value="5">Billing</option>       
         </select>
        </input>
        <input><p>Aff Number</p></input>    
        <input><p>Job Title</p></input>
        <input><p>Contact Source</p></input>
              <input><p>Select Tag(s)</p></input>
         <td>
         <select name="Select_Tags" id="Select_Tags">  
          <option value="61">Already Voted 3-16-17</option>
          <option value="72">Already Voted 3-29-17</option>
          <option value="60">Canvassed3-15-17</option>
          <option value="62">Canvassed3-16-17</option>
          <option value="68">Chinese HP</option>
          <option value="69">Chinese HP - AV</option>
          <option value="2">Company</option>
          <option value="76">CustomListHP-MinusAV-Age20-40Generic</option>
          <option value="75">CustomListHP-MinusAV-Age20-40Latino</option>
          <option value="77">CustomListHP-MinusAV-Age56-85Generic</option>
          <option value="78">CustomListHP-MinusAV-Age56-85Latino</option>
          <option value="74">CustomListHP-MinusAV-Generic</option>
          <option value="73">CustomListHP-MinusAV-Latino</option>
          <option value="55">DanielList-HighPropensity</option>
          <option value="63">DanielList-HighPropensityMinusAV</option>
          <option value="64">DanielList-HighPropensityMinusAV-Latino</option>
          <option value="59">DanielList-HighPropensityNoPAV</option>
          <option value="58">DanielList-HighPropensityNoPAV-Latino</option>
          <option value="54">DanielList-Independents</option>
          <option value="53">DanielList-Republicans</option>
          <option value="65">DeLaFuente-Custom</option>
          <option value="66">Exculde#2</option>
          <option value="3">Government Entity</option>
          <option value="57">Has GeoCode</option>
          <option value="67">Mailer List</option>
          <option value="4">Major Donor</option>
          <option value="1">Non-profit</option>
          <option value="56">PAVs Last 3 Elections</option>
          <option value="71">PrintPDF-EVEN</option>
          <option value="70">PrintPDF-ODD</option>
          <option value="79">Unique Houshold</option>
          <option value="5">Volunteer</option>
           </select></td>
        <input><p>Birth Place</p>
        <input><p>Group(s)</p>
        <input><p>All Tags</p>
        <input><p>Voter ID</p>
        <input><p>Gender*</p>
        <select name="Gender" id="Gender">
         <option>Male</option>
         <option>Female</option>
         <option>Other</option>
         <option>Preferred Not To Ask</option>
        </select>
          </div>
        </div>
            
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
           <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2>Location</h2>
        <input><p>City/Town</p></input>
        <input><p>Country</p></input>
        <input><p>Zip Code</p></input>
       </div>
      </div> 
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
           <div data-role="collapsible">
             <h3>Situs Info</h3>
       <input><p>Address</p></input>
       <input><p>City</p></input>
       <input><p>Zip</p></input>
       <input><p>House Number</p></input>
       <input><p>Unit Abbreviation</p></input>
       <input><p>Unit NUmber</p></input>
       <input><p>Pre Dir</p></input>
       <input><p>Post Dir</p></input>
       <input><p>Mailing Address 1</p></input>
       <input><p>Mailing Address 2</p></input>
       <input><p>Mailing Address 3</p></input>
       <input><p>Mailing Address 4</p></input>
       <input><p>Mailing Zip</p></input>         
      </div> 
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
              <h4>Voter Area</h4>
        <input><p></p></input>
        <input><p>Precinct Name</p></input>
        <input><p>Precinct ID</p></input>
        <input><p>Precinct Portion</p></input>
        <input><p>District ID 0</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict 0</p></input>
        <input><p>District ID 1</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict ID 1</p></input>
        <input><p>District Name 1</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict ID 1</p></input>
        <input><p>District ID 2</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict 2</p></input>
        <input><p>District Name 2</p></input>
        <input><p>District ID 3</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict 3</p></input>
        <input><p>District Name 3</p></input>
        <input><p>District ID 4</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict 4</p></input>
        <input><p>District Name 4</p></input>
        <input><p>District ID 5</p></input>
        <input><p>SubDistrict 5</p></input>
        <input><p>District Name 5</p></input>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
      
     <fieldset>
        <div class="item">
         <div class="submit">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        </div> 
      </div>
       <div class="item last">
        <div class="submit">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Analytics" />        
        </div>
       </div>
     </fieldset>
      
    </form> 
     
   </article>  
  <!---- <aside> ---->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're loading jquery 1..6.4 AND jquery 1.11.3 in the same document?

Comment: I think it was needed by an element I previously had in the file but have since deleted...  Are you saying that including both is the cause of my problems?

Comment: Probably not. Do you think you could make a jsfiddle or codepen demonstrating the problem? Running your code snipped and removing the line doesn't show a background, so I'm assuming it's located in a css file that we don't have access to. If that's the case, the solution might end up being you need to re-order your link tags.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner to html programming and am not sure what you are referring to when you say jsfiddle or codepen.  I just updated the references so that you have access to the css file.

Also, I've tried re-ordering the link tags many ways and had no luck.

Comment: Try inspecting the element (most browsers if developer tools are enabled: right click -> Inspect). In the elements tab, make sure the element with the background is selected. You should see it's styles somewhere in the developer tools. If the background is not visible, you should see that style being crossed out. Try to see if it's background is set to something else above that.

Comment: Thank you @Tazavoo, doing that revealed a line in a jquery css file that was overwritting the background with a color.  I downloaded the file, removed the overwrite, and then began referencing my new custom jquery css instead.  This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be completely wrong but I was advised to import my javascript files at the end of the body section. I think this is so that they don't interfere with your html.

This may possibly be your problem. Just add the javascript files as shown below:

```
                        </article>      
                <!---- <aside> ---->
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
//import here
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="registration_v.0.1/theme_1/js/addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Sorry if this is wrong!!